# While redirecting all pages with .htaccess my codes are conflicting

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, redirect

I am trying to redirect to

> https://example.com from https://www.example.com, http://example.com, http://www.example.com

------------------ and ------------------

> https://example.com/sub_page/pages from
> https://www.example.com/sub_page/pages, http://example.com/sub_page/pages,
> http://www.example.com/sub_page/pages

on .htaccess but my sub_pages are not redirecting properly. probably because of conflicting codes below. I read many articles on Internet but do not fount useful.

> my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I think you got my whole point. In short, I want to *redirect all requests* **to non=www and https**. Please help me with this,

Comment: "but my sub_pages are not redirecting properly" - By the look, they are not being redirected at all. There are no "conflicting codes" in the code you posted. The two rules are arguably in the wrong order, so in the worst case you would get two redirects, but it should still "work" and redirect the request as required. The problem would seem to be _something else_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

That should work in the actual http server configuration or, if you have no access to that, in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess) located in the http hosts's document root.

Comment: There are three URLs that are still not redirected properly _https://www.example.com/sub/page,_ _http://example.com/sub/page,_ _http://www.example.com/sub/page_